# What is the difference between normal salt and salt of guérande?

Tags: flavor, salt, french-cuisine

What is the difference between the salt of guérande `sel de guérande` and normal salt ?

I have a truffle flavored sel de guérande, which have nearly the same taste of normal salt if it doesn't contain truffle flavor.

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/788/what-is-the-difference-between-sea-salt-and-regular-table-salt?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salt is salt is salt.

That being said, most regular salt comes from [salt mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_mining), which tend to be neutral as there is no (or lot less) additional minerals (or other stuff) in the salt that will change the taste.

Sel the Guérande is a [sea salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_salt), it comes from evaporation of sea water, since the sea water contains a lot more minerals and "stuff", like algae.

Depending on the production method, the resulting salt can have different shapes and texture (e.g. guerande is flaky, Maldon is like a "pyramid").

The resulting taste will be subtly different, and will have a different feeling in the mouth when used as a finishing touch on a dish.

Comment: Mined salt comes from ancient sea beds which form the salt mines. The mined salt, if minimally processed, should have trace minerals the same as found in sea salt. The exact minerals and amounts vary according to geographical location, just as it does with sea salt.

Comment: The most important part of the answer is "when used as a finishing touch on a dish". For that, even subtle  taste differences as well colour and taste play a role.